# Spin: gcc-4: error: spawn: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, spin, model-checking

I want to use SPIN model checker on windows7-64 and I have installed all the prerequisites of it. Below is the procedure how I did it

1. I installed gcc compiler with cygwin .. updated path checked with command
   prompt it shows version 4.9.2
2. Installed Active Tcl .. updated path .. works fine when I open ispin.
3. Updated path with ispin directory as well.
4. Just a bit of trick, also check by giving exact path of gcc.exe inside ispin file. But the error remained same.

But when I try to compile pre included example files (e.g leader.pml), it gives me the error

```
spin: preprocessing failed
gcc-4: error: spawn: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and/or missing ? and how can I fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you configured the correct name for the GCC executable? You didn't say `gcc-4`? Have you made sure there is a `gcc-4` executable in the path?

Comment: Are you using `gcc` from `/usr/bin/gcc` ?

Comment: in the directory **C:\cygwin64\bin** it shows me **gcc.exe** and not gcc-4. I tried changing gcc.exe to gcc-4.exe but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps some `gcc-...` packages are missing. Try installing `gcc-mingw-g++` (or something else)

Answer (score 1):

In cygwin\bin, copy gcc twice, name one gcc-3, the other gcc-4, but also leave plain gcc there.